# After logout the user in a website he lost their user saved data of the previous session

Tags: .net, vb.net, authentication, browser, webbrowser-control

This is the scenario, I'm trying to realize a `winforms` application for a person of my family.

He need to acces to a (porn) website to publish some kind of publicity and to gain some kind of points while he stay connected, he says that this kind of websites are the best to do this, well, I'm not anybody to question that, I just do what he need.

Well, I don't know too much of networking, but the website is based on frames, this is the way that I log in:

```
private sub log_in()

    ' Firstly, navigate to the main page. (Ex: www.website.com)
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(url)

    ' Secondly, navigate to the login page .
    ' (seems that If I directly navigate to this page I can't log in, 
    ' so first of all I need to navigate to the main page)
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(url & "/main/login.php")


    ' Put username/password on the textboxes.
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id_username").InnerText = user.ToString()
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id_password").InnerText = pass.ToString()

    ' click the button to submit login.
    WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument.forms(0).submit()

    ' At this point I'm looged in.

End sub
```

While the user is connected he gain some kinda of points (don't ask me how, I don't know), the problem is that when the session finishes (I mean, when I logout from the site to re-login to the site), all the points are lost, but this does not happen when the user logs directly from the navigator, this only happens when the user logs in from my app.

This is the way that I log out:

```
Private Sub log_out()

    ' Simple as this, just I acces to the logout frame
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(url & "/00000000000000000000000000000000/main/logout/")

End Sub
```

Then I need a solution to keep alive those user session points after logout, I don't know if the problem is that I need to manage cookies or what I need to do, because like I've said I don't know too much about networking.

PS: If I need to give the url just tell me, I don't know if giving a porn url is breaking the SO rules.

Comment: Maybe the site is using cookies?  I'm not sure how to retain cookies in a `WebBrowser` control, but that might be a good place to start looking.

Comment: @David I keep in this problem from 1 year ago, you can see that I've started the first question of this problem here (which is a different question): http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1248295+cookie in this time I've tried to manage cookies bymyself for this site but I've don't learned right how to do it, and also the most important thing is that I don't know if the cookies would be the solution. thanks for comment!

Comment: Why people have been so incomprehensive with this question?. I think that I've demostrated `a minimal understanding of the problem being solved`, also I've tried to explain the problem, also I gave you the problem factors. Of course there is one thing that I can't understand in all of this question, otherwise I don't should need to ask for help. Please, can reopen this question?, or at least close it with a real reason?.

Comment: You can install Fiddler 2 http://fiddler2.com/
And then you can see all requests with all attributes. I hope, this analysis help you.

Comment: Love it how you clarify what you mean by "finishing the session" :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a URL would help, I have some ideas/assumptions that might help answer your question.

Assuming that the points you gain do not give you badges, but something more tangible (eg. cash), setting points by cookie is unlikely. It is to easy to adjust the cookie, and with that maipulate/cheat the point-system.
If this assumption is wrong, you could use Firebug/firecookie, or Chromes webdev tools (under resources, it says cookies) to inspect the cookies.

However, are you sure you are gaining points? It could be that your winforms program doesn't do the things needed to gain those points, and thus when you logout-login there are no points since you never acquired them.

As it is uncommon to store points to the server at logout, or to store those on the user-end altogether, i think we can rule out any login/logout and user-side issues.

What might be happening is that you earn points by doing your acitivity in a website, which is loaded in a frame by the "points system" 
In that case it might be that travelling to the website with `WebBrowser1.Navigate(url)` is not enough, as it doesn't load either the frame of the "points system", or not the correct website inside the frame.

anyway, there are a lot open ends here. some more info on the points system/website (and thus a URL would come in handy) could allow us to solve your problem.

**== QUICK EDIT ==**

the website uses PHP Sessions. The session ID is stored in a cookie.
What if you catch and keep that cookie? Does that influence anything?

Comment: `Although a URL would help` Yes I know but a moderator edited my last modification to delete the url so I want to respect it, but you can see the deleted url in her edit by clicking at the button that says "edited Nov 29 at 17:27", is the deleted hyperlink that says `Click here to go to the url` that moderator deleted. Now you can see the url (I hope that you could give me more hints or discard solutions/problems after seeying that webpage).

Comment: Sorry but I have no much more information about the points system, the points are like a Ranking points, those points make you more "popular" when you stay more time online in the page, the account owner told me that using my application (a simple webbrowser control) he can gain those points while he stays connected but after closing the program to relogin using the program the points are lost.

Comment: I've read your quick edit, thankyou so much for verifying/confirm what kind of session based it is, that can help me to the next step which is get/store the cookie and ¿send it before unlog?. Maybe I'm asking too much if I ask you for how to start doing all that? or give me documented urls?

Comment: sorry, can't help you with that, I've never made winform apps, but basically PHP sessions IDs are send with a url (GET) or (it looks like) in this case it reads the cookie (the cookie gets destroyed when the session ends, if you store it somewhere before that, and just recreate it with the same contents, the website does the rest)

Comment: I did it! was so simple than managing the webBrowser.Document.Cookie property to get it and set it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could rule out cookies by following these steps:

1) logging into the site manually via a browser

2) accumulating some points

3) logging out

4) logging back in to confirm your points from the previous session still exist

5) log out again and this time clear all browser history/cookies/temp files

6) finally log back in

If the points are gone it is cookie based.  If the points still exist, they are more than likely kept track of server side which indicates there's another trigger for accumulating points other than simply being logged in (i.e. navigation throughout the site).

Comment: Thanks so much for the steps, I could need some days to be able to say you that it is a cookie based site or isn't, because I'm not the owner of the account and also I don't know how to manage (gain) those points, I need to comunicate the steps and wait the response from the account owner. but, in case that it is a cookie based site then, you could say me what I could do to solve it?. I've tried to send a cookie container a few times unsucessfully (I'm newbie with that)

Comment: First step is to identify the tracking mechanism.  Today's sites probably won't reward a user for simply being logged in, they will most likely reward a user for contributing to their revenue in some fashion (for example: viewing a new page every few seconds so they can display ad's to that user and in turn make money).